# The "" cache configuration does not exist

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

I am updating a project from CakePHP 3.5 to 4.0.
In one of my models, I am doing this:

```
    public function afterSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity)
    {
        Cache::clear(false, 'dbResults');
    }
```

This works in the "old" version of my project with CakePHP 3.5, but fails with CakePHP 4.0 with the error

```
The "" cache configuration does not exist.#0 /var/www/repo/public/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Cache/Cache.php(230): Cake\Cache\Cache::_buildEngine('')
```

I don't understand why the code tries to search for a configuration with empty string `""`.

Here is the relevant part of my `app.php` config file:

```
    'Cache' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'File',
            'prefix' => 'headless_',
            'path' => CACHE,
            'url' => env('CACHE_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
        '_cake_core_' => [
            'className' => 'File',
            'prefix' => 'headless_cake_core_',
            'path' => CACHE . 'persistent/',
            'serialize' => true,
            'duration' => '+2 minutes',
            'url' => env('CACHE_CAKECORE_URL', null),
        ],
        '_cake_model_' => [
            'className' => 'File',
            'prefix' => 'headless_cake_model_',
            'path' => CACHE . 'models/',
            'serialize' => true,
            'duration' => '+2 minutes',
            'url' => env('CACHE_CAKEMODEL_URL', null),
        ],

        'permissions' => [
            'className' => 'File',
            'prefix' => 'headless_',
            'path' => CACHE . 'permissions/',
            'url' => env('CACHE_PERMISSIONS_URL', null),
        ],

        'dbResults' => [
            'className' => 'File',
            'prefix' => 'headless_',
            'path' => CACHE . 'dbResults/',
            'url' => env('CACHE_PERMISSIONS_URL', null),
            'duration' => '+1440 minutes',
        ],

        'pages' => [
            'className' => 'File',
            'prefix' => 'page_',
            'path' => CACHE . 'pages/',
            'serialize' => true,
            'duration' => '+320 minutes',
        ],

        'page_contents' => [
            'className' => 'File',
            'prefix' => 'pc_',
            'path' => CACHE . 'page_contents/',
            'serialize' => true,
            'duration' => '+320 minutes',
        ],
    ],
```

In addition to that, in my `bootstrap.php` file I am doing

```
Cache::setConfig(Configure::consume('Cache'));
```

I don't understand why I get this error when everything seems to be properly configured.

Comment: The `clear` function takes only one parameter, the name of the cache configuration to clear.

Comment: @GregSchmidt that was the issue, thanks. The signature of the `clear` method changed from Cake 3 to Cake 4. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update the following line

```
Cache::clear('dbResults');
```

In CakePHP 4, Cache::clear() accepts only one parameter as opposed to CakePHP 3. They removed the `$check` parameter. Unfortunately migration guide does not seem to be updated about this.

Reference:
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/caching.html#clearing-cached-data